# Magento 2 page redirection to CMS pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, forms, redirect

I want to redirect to two different CMS Pages when a custom form is submitted.
Can any one help how we can do this. I'm trying form the .phtml template to get the CMS Page's ID and then redirect to that page.
Please correct me if I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance,
regrards,
kiran.

Comment: What is the magento version you are using as you have mentioned magento1.9 and magento 2 both? you can achieve this my adding redirection code to your postAction of that custom form.

Comment: I'm using magento 2.2.3 In the phtml page i want  to include the cms page content in that way I'm trying. Is it worng

Comment: Why do you want to show cms page content on phtml? You can create static block for this.